# Transition bullet point nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I create a sticky navbar with the vertical bar on the right and a bullet point (the circle):

**http://retail.cegid.com/fr/avril-2020-votre-newsletter-clients/**

My HTML :

```js
// Jquery nav 
/*
 * jQuery One Page Nav Plugin
 * http://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Trevor Davis (http://trevordavis.net)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * Uses the same license as jQuery, see:
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * @version 3.0.0
 *
 * Example usage:
 * $('#nav').onePageNav({
 *   currentClass: 'current',
 *   changeHash: false,
 *   scrollSpeed: 750
 * });
 */

;(function($, window, document, undefined){

    // our plugin constructor
    var OnePageNav = function(elem, options){
        this.elem = elem;
        this.$elem = $(elem);
        this.options = options;
        this.metadata = this.$elem.data('plugin-options');
        this.$win = $(window);
        this.sections = {};
        this.didScroll = false;
        this.$doc = $(document);
        this.docHeight = this.$doc.height();
    };

    // the plugin prototype
    OnePageNav.prototype = {
        defaults: {
            navItems: 'a',
            currentClass: 'current',
            changeHash: false,
            easing: 'swing',
            filter: '',
            scrollSpeed: 750,
            scrollThreshold: 0.5,
            begin: false,
            end: false,
            scrollChange: false
        },

        init: function() {
            // Introduce defaults that can be extended either
            // globally or using an object literal.
            this.config = $.extend({}, this.defaults, this.options, this.metadata);

            this.$nav = this.$elem.find(this.config.navItems);

            //Filter any links out of the nav
            if(this.config.filter !== '') {
                this.$nav = this.$nav.filter(this.config.filter);
            }

            //Handle clicks on the nav
            this.$nav.on('click.onePageNav', $.proxy(this.handleClick, this));

            //Get the section positions
            this.getPositions();

            //Handle scroll changes
            this.bindInterval();

            //Update the positions on resize too
            this.$win.on('resize.onePageNav', $.proxy(this.getPositions, this));

            return this;
        },

        adjustNav: function(self, $parent) {
            self.$elem.find('.' + self.config.currentClass).removeClass(self.config.currentClass);
            $parent.addClass(self.config.currentClass);
        },

        bindInterval: function() {
            var self = this;
            var docHeight;

            self.$win.on('scroll.onePageNav', function() {
                self.didScroll = true;
            });

            self.t = setInterval(function() {
                docHeight = self.$doc.height();

                //If it was scrolled
                if(self.didScroll) {
                    self.didScroll = false;
                    self.scrollChange();
                }

                //If the document height changes
                if(docHeight !== self.docHeight) {
                    self.docHeight = docHeight;
                    self.getPositions();
                }
            }, 250);
        },

        getHash: function($link) {
            return $link.attr('href').split('#')[1];
        },

        getPositions: function() {
            var self = this;
            var linkHref;
            var topPos;
            var $target;

            self.$nav.each(function() {
                linkHref = self.getHash($(this));
                $target = $('#' + linkHref);

                if($target.length) {
                    topPos = $target.offset().top;
                    self.sections[linkHref] = Math.round(topPos);
                }
            });
        },

        getSection: function(windowPos) {
            var returnValue = null;
            var windowHeight = Math.round(this.$win.height() * this.config.scrollThreshold);

            for(var section in this.sections) {
                if((this.sections[section] - windowHeight) < windowPos) {
                    returnValue = section;
                }
            }

            return returnValue;
        },

        handleClick: function(e) {
            var self = this;
            var $link = $(e.currentTarget);
            var $parent = $link.parent();
            var newLoc = '#' + self.getHash($link);

            if(!$parent.hasClass(self.config.currentClass)) {
                //Start callback
                if(self.config.begin) {
                    self.config.begin();
                }

                //Change the highlighted nav item
                self.adjustNav(self, $parent);

                //Removing the auto-adjust on scroll
                self.unbindInterval();

                //Scroll to the correct position
                self.scrollTo(newLoc, function() {
                    //Do we need to change the hash?
                    if(self.config.changeHash) {
                        window.location.hash = newLoc;
                    }

                    //Add the auto-adjust on scroll back in
                    self.bindInterval();

                    //End callback
                    if(self.config.end) {
                        self.config.end();
                    }
                });
            }

            e.preventDefault();
        },

        scrollChange: function() {
            var windowTop = this.$win.scrollTop();
            var position = this.getSection(windowTop);
            var $parent;

            //If the position is set
            if(position !== null) {
                $parent = this.$elem.find('a[href$="#' + position + '"]').parent();

                //If it's not already the current section
                if(!$parent.hasClass(this.config.currentClass)) {
                    //Change the highlighted nav item
                    this.adjustNav(this, $parent);

                    //If there is a scrollChange callback
                    if(this.config.scrollChange) {
                        this.config.scrollChange($parent);
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        scrollTo: function(target, callback) {
            var offset = $(target).offset().top;

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: offset
            }, this.config.scrollSpeed, this.config.easing, callback);
        },

        unbindInterval: function() {
            clearInterval(this.t);
            this.$win.unbind('scroll.onePageNav');
        }
    };

    OnePageNav.defaults = OnePageNav.prototype.defaults;

    $.fn.onePageNav = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            new OnePageNav(this, options).init();
        });
    };

})( jQuery, window , document );

 //Myjquery
 
 $('.uagb-toc__list-wrap').append('<div id="menu_slider"><div id="menu_slider_circle" style="top: 50%;"></div></div>');
    console.log('uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu');

        var $nav = $('.uagb-toc__list-wrap');

        $nav.onePageNav();
```

```css
.wp-block-uagb-table-of-contents {
     margin-top: 2rem;
   background-color: white;
}
 .wp-block-uagb-table-of-contents ul {
     margin: 0 !important;
}
 .wp-block-uagb-table-of-contents ul li {
     list-style: none;
}
 .wp-block-uagb-table-of-contents ul li:before {
     content: none;
}
 .wp-block-uagb-table-of-contents ul li.current a {
     font-weight: bold;
     opacity: 1;
     transform: scale(1);
}
 .wp-block-uagb-table-of-contents ul li a {
     color: red;
     font-weight: 700;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .uagb-toc__wrap {
   background: teal;
     display: flex !important;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: flex-end;
}
 .uagb-toc__wrap .uagb-toc__title-wrap span.uag-toc__collapsible-wrap {
     display: none;
}
/* ////////////////////////////////// */
/* //////////// MENU ///////////// */
/* //////////////////////////////// */
 .uagb-toc__list-wrap {
     position: fixed;
     top: 50%;
     right: 60px;
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
     transform: translateY(-50%);
    /* background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.31);
    */
}
 .uagb-toc__list {
     color: #002c52;
     padding: 0 30px;
}
 .uagb-toc__list li {
     display: block;
     text-align: right;
     opacity: 0.5;
     padding: 1vh 0;
     cursor: pointer;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
     transition: all 0.4s ease;
     -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
     transform-origin: 100% 50%;
     -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
     transform: scale(0.9);
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 9px #fff, 1px 1px 4px #fff;
}
 #menu_slider {
     position: absolute;
     width: 2px;
     height: 100%;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     background: rgba(0, 44, 82, 0.4);
}
 #menu_slider_circle {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0%;
     left: 1px;
     width: 10px;
     height: 10px;
     border-radius: 30px;
     background: rgba(0, 44, 82, 1);
     -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
     transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
 #menu_slider_circle::before {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: -8px;
     left: -8px;
     bottom: -8px;
     right: -8px;
     border-radius: 60px;
     background: rgba(0, 44, 82, .1);
}
 #menu_titles, #menu_slider, #menu_slider_circle, #menu.white #menu_slider_circle::before {
     -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
     transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
 #menu.white #menu_titles {
     color: #fff;
}
 #menu.white #menu_titles span {
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 9px #002c52, 1px 1px 4px #002c52;
}
 #menu.white #menu_slider {
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
}
 #menu.white #menu_slider_circle {
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
 #menu.white #menu_slider_circle::before {
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}
 #menu_toggle {
     position: absolute;
     width: 60px;
     height: 60px;
     top: 0;
     left: -60px;
     background: #002c52 url(img/burger.svg) center no-repeat;
     display: none;
     background-size: 80%;
}
 #menu.showed #menu_toggle {
     background-image: url(img/cross.svg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script> </head>
<body>
<div class="wp-block-column" style="flex-basis:66.66%">
                <span id="titre-h2" class="uag-toc__heading-anchor"></span>
                <h2 id="1-de-ere-rzer">Titre H2</h2>


                <p>ere&nbsp;<strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>&nbsp;est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l’imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de pimprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n’a pas faitre cinq siècles, mais s’est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n’en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker.e&nbsp;<strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>&nbsp;est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l’imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n’a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s’est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n’en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker.</p>


                <p>ze
                </p>


                <span id="titre-h3" class="uag-toc__heading-anchor"></span>
                <h3>Titre H3</h3>


                <span id="titre-h4" class="uag-toc__heading-anchor"></span>
                <h4>Titre H4</h4>


                <p>
                    rze</p>


                <span id="autre-titre-h2" class="uag-toc__heading-anchor"></span>
                <h2 id="2-r-ze">Autre titre H2</h2>


                <p>r zerze rze
                </p>


                <p>
                    rz</p>


                <div class="wp-block-media-text alignwide is-stacked-on-mobile">
                    <figure class="wp-block-media-text__media"><img src="http://jobs.alterway.tma/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/05/xgu472hf2_by_lariliikala.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-604" srcset="http://jobs.alterway.tma/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/05/xgu472hf2_by_lariliikala.jpg 980w, http://jobs.alterway.tma/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/05/xgu472hf2_by_lariliikala-300x188.jpg 300w, http://jobs.alterway.tma/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/05/xgu472hf2_by_lariliikala-768x480.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 980px) 100vw, 980px"></figure>
                    <div class="wp-block-media-text__content">
                        <p class="has-large-font-size">ddazedazdazdazdazdazda</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>










    <div class="wp-block-uagb-table-of-contents uagb-toc__align-left uagb-toc__columns-undefined uagb-block-84b71cc1-d86a-477b-a4d8-13ad158cfc23" data-scroll="true" data-offset="30" data-delay="800">
        <div class="uagb-toc__wrap">
            <div class="uagb-toc__title-wrap uagb-toc__is-collapsible">
                <div class="uagb-toc__title">Sommaire</div>
                <span class="uag-toc__collapsible-wrap">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 320 512">
                        <path d="M143 352.3L7 216.3c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9l22.6-22.6c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l96.4 96.4 96.4-96.4c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l22.6 22.6c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9l-136 136c-9.2 9.4-24.4 9.4-33.8 0z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="uagb-toc__list-wrap" data-headers="">
                <ul class="uagb-toc__list">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#titre-h2">Titre H2</a>
                    </li>
                    <ul class="uagb-toc__list">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#titre-h3">Titre H3</a>
                        </li>
                        <ul class="uagb-toc__list">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#titre-h4">Titre H4</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#autre-titre-h2">Autre titre H2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
{# Menu ancres #}
<div class="wp-block-uagb-table-of-contents uagb-toc__align-left uagb-toc__columns-undefined uagb-block-84b71cc1-d86a-477b-a4d8-13ad158cfc23" data-scroll="true" data-offset="30" data-delay="800">
    <div class="uagb-toc__wrap">
        <div class="uagb-toc__title-wrap uagb-toc__is-collapsible">
            <div class="uagb-toc__title">Sommaire</div>
            <span class="uag-toc__collapsible-wrap">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 320 512">
                    <path d="M143 352.3L7 216.3c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9l22.6-22.6c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l96.4 96.4 96.4-96.4c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l22.6 22.6c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9l-136 136c-9.2 9.4-24.4 9.4-33.8 0z"></path>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="uagb-toc__list-wrap" data-headers="[{&quot;tag&quot;:2,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Titre H2&quot;,&quot;link&quot;:&quot;titre-h2&quot;,&quot;content&quot;:&quot;Titre H2&quot;,&quot;level&quot;:0},{&quot;tag&quot;:3,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Titre H3&quot;,&quot;link&quot;:&quot;titre-h3&quot;,&quot;content&quot;:&quot;Titre H3&quot;,&quot;level&quot;:1},{&quot;tag&quot;:4,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Titre H4&quot;,&quot;link&quot;:&quot;titre-h4&quot;,&quot;content&quot;:&quot;Titre H4&quot;,&quot;level&quot;:2},{&quot;tag&quot;:2,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Autre titre H2&quot;,&quot;link&quot;:&quot;autre-titre-h2&quot;,&quot;content&quot;:&quot;Autre titre H2&quot;,&quot;level&quot;:0}]">
            <ul class="uagb-toc__list">
                <li>
                    <a href="#titre-h2">Titre H2</a>
                </li>
                <ul class="uagb-toc__list">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#titre-h3">Titre H3</a>
                    </li>
                    <ul class="uagb-toc__list">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#titre-h4">Titre H4</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#autre-titre-h2">Autre titre H2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit js:

```
var fn_menu_ancres = function () {
    $('.uagb-toc__list-wrap').append('<div id="menu_slider"><div id="menu_slider_circle" style="top: 50%;"></div></div>');
    console.log('uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu');



};
```

Edit CSS :

```
    .wp-block-uagb-table-of-contents {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    .uagb-toc__list-wrap{
        // position: relative;
    }

    ul {
        li {
            list-style: none;
            &:before {
                content: none;
            }

            &.active {
                a {
                    font-weight: bold;
                    opacity: 1;
                    transform: scale(1);
                }
            }

            a {
                color: teal;
                font-weight: $fw-light;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        }
    }
}

.uagb-toc__wrap {
    display: flex!important;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;

    .uagb-toc__title-wrap {
        span.uag-toc__collapsible-wrap {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}




/* ////////////////////////////////// */
/* ////////////  MENU  ///////////// */
/* //////////////////////////////// */


.uagb-toc__list-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 60px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
/*    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.31);*/
}


.uagb-toc__list {
    // font-size: 1.6em;
    color: #002c52;
    padding: 0 30px;
}

.uagb-toc__list li{
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    opacity: .5;
    padding: 1vh 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
            transition: all .4s ease;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
            transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.9);
            transform: scale(.9);

    text-shadow: 1px 1px 9px #fff, 1px 1px 4px #fff;
}

.uagb-toc__list li:hover {
/*    font-size: 1.6em;*/
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
}

.uagb-toc__list li.active {
/*    font-size: 1.6em;*/
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
}

#menu_slider {
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 44, 82, 0.4);
}

#menu_slider_circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 1px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: rgba(0, 44, 82, 1);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

#menu_slider_circle::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    left: -8px;
    bottom: -8px;
    right: -8px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    background: rgba(0, 44, 82, .1);
}

#menu_titles,
#menu_slider,
#menu_slider_circle,
#menu.white #menu_slider_circle::before {
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
            transition: all .4s ease;
}

#menu.white #menu_titles{
    color: #fff;
}

#menu.white #menu_titles span{
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 9px rgb(0, 44, 82), 1px 1px 4px rgb(0, 44, 82);
}

#menu.white #menu_slider {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
}

#menu.white #menu_slider_circle {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

#menu.white #menu_slider_circle::before {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

#menu_toggle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    top: 0;
    left: -60px;
    background: #002c52 url(img/burger.svg) center no-repeat;
    display: none;
    background-size: 80%;
}

#menu.showed #menu_toggle {
    background-image: url(img/cross.svg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1460px) {
    #menu {
        right: 30px;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
                transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    #menu, #menu.white {
        background: #fff;
        right: 0;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0px rgba(0, 44, 82, .4);
        -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
                transition: all .4s ease;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    #menu.showed {
        box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0, 44, 82, .4);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
                transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    #menu_titles {
        padding: 0;
    }
    #menu.white #menu_titles{
        color: #002c52;
    }
    #menu_titles span{
        display: block;
        padding: 1vh 30px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 44, 82, .4);
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
                transform: scale(1);
    }
    .uagb-toc__list li.active {
        background: #002c52;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #fff;
    }

    #menu_toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    #menu_slider {
        display: none;
    }

    #menu.white #menu_slider {
        background: rgba(0, 44, 82, .4);
    }

    #menu.white #menu_slider_circle {
        background: rgba(20, 44, 82, 1);
    }

    #menu.white #menu_slider_circle::before {
        background: rgba(20, 44, 82, .1);
    }
}
```

I have the JS that makes it sticky, but I need the vertical bar and the bullet point ((the circle).

PS: I can't touch the HTML, I have to make all of this with only CSS and JS.

Here is a screenshot :
-SCROLL MORE-
https://ibb.co/fNp12pH

Comment: Using CSS fixed position and a JS window scroll listener that compares scroll position to the position of each section would be my first thoughts.

Comment: There's quite a lot here: styling the scroll bar with the circle, animating it moving, detecting when to move it.. To get the best out of this site, you're probably best trying to do one of these things then come back here and post your results if you run into problems.

Comment: @RichardHunter i edited my post, can you check please (JS and CS)

Comment: It's quite hard to look through so much code and find any particular problem. Would you be able to create an example, perhaps using jsfiddle.net (which supports SCSS), so we can see the code working?

Comment: @RichardHunter can you check please

Comment: I can see errors being thrown in the console. I notice you're using the onePageNav plugin. You can see in the source code that it has instructions for usage: ` * Example usage:
 * $('#nav').onePageNav({
 *   currentClass: 'current',
 *   changeHash: false,
 *   scrollSpeed: 750
 * });` but you're not actually passing any such configuration object in your own code, so that could be a problem.

Comment: i wrote some sections now, you can check :)

Comment: @RichardHunter  actually, im looking for a way to move the bullet point (circle) when user scroll or click on an href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution to the problem. It would be preferable to carry this out with CSS, but the constraint of not changing around the HTML made that impossible (as far as I can tell).

A few things to note:
You're using a JQuery plugin which you've just copied and pasted here. As it turns out, this was rather fortuitous because I had to fix a problem with the plug-in itself. I needed the `begin` callback to be passing the element being clicked on, but it wasn't doing this, so I added it in. This means though that this solution wont work with the OnePageNav plug-in as it stands. I personally don't think it matters if you just import it into your own code because it isn't very big, and also it doesn't seem to be maintained anymore, so there probably wont be any more releases of it anyway.

I've also edited your code quite a bit in order to remove things which weren't relevant to the problem in hand to make it easier for me to understand. I also want to the solution to be as general as possible so that other people might be able to benefit from this too. I've kept the 'spirit' of your code though so I don't think you should have any problems should you want to adopt this solution.

```js
// Jquery nav 
/*
 * jQuery One Page Nav Plugin
 * http://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Trevor Davis (http://trevordavis.net)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * Uses the same license as jQuery, see:
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * @version 3.0.0
 *
 * Example usage:
 * $('#nav').onePageNav({
 *   currentClass: 'current',
 *   changeHash: false,
 *   scrollSpeed: 750
 * });
 */

;
(function($, window, document, undefined) {

  // our plugin constructor
  var OnePageNav = function(elem, options) {
    this.elem = elem;
    this.$elem = $(elem);
    this.options = options;
    this.metadata = this.$elem.data('plugin-options');
    this.$win = $(window);
    this.sections = {};
    this.didScroll = false;
    this.$doc = $(document);
    this.docHeight = this.$doc.height();
  };

  // the plugin prototype
  OnePageNav.prototype = {
    defaults: {
      navItems: 'a',
      currentClass: 'current',
      changeHash: false,
      easing: 'swing',
      filter: '',
      scrollSpeed: 750,
      scrollThreshold: 0.5,
      begin: false,
      end: false,
      scrollChange: false
    },

    init: function() {
      // Introduce defaults that can be extended either
      // globally or using an object literal.
      this.config = $.extend({}, this.defaults, this.options, this.metadata);

      this.$nav = this.$elem.find(this.config.navItems);

      //Filter any links out of the nav
      if (this.config.filter !== '') {
        this.$nav = this.$nav.filter(this.config.filter);
      }

      //Handle clicks on the nav
      this.$nav.on('click.onePageNav', $.proxy(this.handleClick, this));

      //Get the section positions
      this.getPositions();

      //Handle scroll changes
      this.bindInterval();

      //Update the positions on resize too
      this.$win.on('resize.onePageNav', $.proxy(this.getPositions, this));

      return this;
    },

    adjustNav: function(self, $parent) {
      self.$elem.find('.' + self.config.currentClass).removeClass(self.config.currentClass);
      $parent.addClass(self.config.currentClass);
    },

    bindInterval: function() {
      var self = this;
      var docHeight;

      self.$win.on('scroll.onePageNav', function() {
        self.didScroll = true;
      });

      self.t = setInterval(function() {
        docHeight = self.$doc.height();

        //If it was scrolled
        if (self.didScroll) {
          self.didScroll = false;
          self.scrollChange();
        }

        //If the document height changes
        if (docHeight !== self.docHeight) {
          self.docHeight = docHeight;
          self.getPositions();
        }
      }, 250);
    },

    getHash: function($link) {
      return $link.attr('href').split('#')[1];
    },

    getPositions: function() {
      var self = this;
      var linkHref;
      var topPos;
      var $target;

      self.$nav.each(function() {
        linkHref = self.getHash($(this));
        $target = $('#' + linkHref);

        if ($target.length) {
          topPos = $target.offset().top;
          self.sections[linkHref] = Math.round(topPos);
        }
      });
    },

    getSection: function(windowPos) {
      var returnValue = null;
      var windowHeight = Math.round(this.$win.height() * this.config.scrollThreshold);

      for (var section in this.sections) {
        if ((this.sections[section] - windowHeight) < windowPos) {
          returnValue = section;
        }
      }

      return returnValue;
    },

    handleClick: function(e) {
      var self = this;
      var $link = $(e.currentTarget);
      var $parent = $link.parent();
      var newLoc = '#' + self.getHash($link);

      if (!$parent.hasClass(self.config.currentClass)) {
        //Start callback
        if (self.config.begin) {
          self.config.begin($link);
        }

        //Change the highlighted nav item
        self.adjustNav(self, $parent);

        //Removing the auto-adjust on scroll
        self.unbindInterval();

        //Scroll to the correct position
        self.scrollTo(newLoc, function() {
          //Do we need to change the hash?
          if (self.config.changeHash) {
            window.location.hash = newLoc;
          }

          //Add the auto-adjust on scroll back in
          self.bindInterval();

          //End callback
          if (self.config.end) {
            self.config.end();
          }
        });
      }

      e.preventDefault();
    },

    scrollChange: function() {
      var windowTop = this.$win.scrollTop();
      var position = this.getSection(windowTop);
      var $parent;

      //If the position is set
      if (position !== null) {
        $parent = this.$elem.find('a[href$="#' + position + '"]').parent();

        //If it's not already the current section
        if (!$parent.hasClass(this.config.currentClass)) {
          //Change the highlighted nav item
          this.adjustNav(this, $parent);

          //If there is a scrollChange callback
          if (this.config.scrollChange) {
            this.config.scrollChange($parent);
          }
        }
      }
    },

    scrollTo: function(target, callback) {
      var offset = $(target).offset().top;

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offset
      }, this.config.scrollSpeed, this.config.easing, callback);
    },

    unbindInterval: function() {
      clearInterval(this.t);
      this.$win.unbind('scroll.onePageNav');
    }
  };

  OnePageNav.defaults = OnePageNav.prototype.defaults;

  $.fn.onePageNav = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      new OnePageNav(this, options).init();
    });
  };

})(jQuery, window, document);

var $nav = $('.uagb-toc__list-wrap');

function calculatePercentage(currentEl, containerEl) {
  const {
    y,
    height
  } = currentEl.getBoundingClientRect();

  const {
    y: containerY,
    height: containerHeight
  } = containerEl.getBoundingClientRect();

  const offsetTop = y - containerY;
  return (offsetTop + (height / 2)) / containerHeight * 100
}

$nav.onePageNav({
  currentClass: 'current',
  begin: function($link) {
    updateMenuSlider($link[0]);
  },
  scrollChange: function($currentListItem) {
    updateMenuSlider($currentListItem[0]);
  },
});

function updateMenuSlider(currentEl) {
  const containerEl = $('.uagb-toc__list-wrap')[0];
  const percentage = calculatePercentage(currentEl, containerEl);
  positionCircle(percentage);
}

function positionCircle(percent) {
  $('#menu_slider_circle').css('top', percent + '%');
}
```

```css
.wp-block-uagb-table-of-contents {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  background-color: white;
}

.uagb-toc__list-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 60px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul.uagb-toc__list {
  margin: 0;
  color: #002c52;
  background: antiquewhite;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  opacity: 0.5;
  padding: 1vh 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 9px #fff, 1px 1px 4px #fff;
}

li a {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li.current a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

#menu_slider {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 44, 82, 0.4);
}

#menu_slider_circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 1px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: rgba(0, 44, 82, 1);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transition: .4s top ease;
}

#menu_slider_circle::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  bottom: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  background: rgba(0, 44, 82, .1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wp-block-column" style="flex-basis:66.66%">
  <span id="titre-h2" class="uag-toc__heading-anchor"></span>
  <h2 id="1-de-ere-rzer">Titre H2</h2>
  <p>est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l’imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réa.</p>
  <p>implement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l’imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réa.</p>
  <p>implement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l’imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réa.</p>
  <p>implement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l’imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réa.</p>

  <span id="titre-h3" class="uag-toc__heading-anchor"></span>
  <h3>Titre H3</h3>
  <p>implement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l’imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réa.</p>
  <p>implement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l’imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réa.</p>
  <p>implement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l’imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réa.</p>

  <span id="titre-h4" class="uag-toc__heading-anchor"></span>
  <h4>Titre H4</h4>

  <p>implement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l’imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réa.</p>
  <p>implement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l’imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réa.</p>
  <p>implement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l’imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réa.</p>

  <span id="autre-titre-h2" class="uag-toc__heading-anchor"></span>
  <h2 id="2-r-ze">Autre titre H2</h2>

  <p>implement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l’imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réa.</p>
  <p>implement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l’imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réa.</p>
  <p>implement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l’imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réa.</p>
</div>

<div class="wp-block-uagb-table-of-contents uagb-toc__align-left uagb-toc__columns-undefined uagb-block-84b71cc1-d86a-477b-a4d8-13ad158cfc23" data-scroll="true" data-offset="30" data-delay="800">
  <div class="uagb-toc__wrap">

    <div class="uagb-toc__list-wrap" data-headers="">

      <div id="menu_slider">
        <div id="menu_slider_circle"></div>
      </div>

      <ul class="uagb-toc__list">
        <li>
          <a href="#titre-h2">Titre H2</a>
        </li>
        <ul class="uagb-toc__list">
          <li>
            <a href="#titre-h3">Titre H3</a>
          </li>
          <ul class="uagb-toc__list">
            <li>
              <a href="#titre-h4">Titre H4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#autre-titre-h2">Autre titre H2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :)
When i used the js code, i had this error with the gulp : ** 'scriptApp' errored after 2.19 s
[11:17:41] GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: SyntaxError: Name expected
File: /home/machemlal/Documents/AW/CEGID/cegid-webfactory/design-system/src/script/app/app.js**

Comment: this code caused this error :  `const {
    y,
    height
  } = currentEl.getBoundingClientRect();

  const {
    y: containerY,
    height: containerHeight
  } = containerEl.getBoundingClientRect();` what could I replace it with please ?

Comment: Seemingly your minifier doesn't understand destructuring. Writing it without the destructuring would be my first try. something like: var bcr = currentEl.getBoundingClientRect(); var y = bcr.y; var height = bcr.height; and so on. I might also consider updating GulpUglify as there's some chance it's severely out of date

Comment: thanks i found it in https://es6console.com/kgan7z97/ You are using ES6, and im using ES5, so i converted it :)

Comment: Glad you've got it sorted.

Comment: Richard Hunter is there a way to scroll ? because i have o header and the sectoin commes uder it :/

Comment: Scroll what, sorry?

Comment: i have a  <header> in my page that is sticky, and when i click on a <a href="#title-1"> title 1 </a> it scroll to the concerned section but this section is under the sticky header, so i need to scroll a little more to about 116px (header height)

Comment: That's an issue with onePageNav plugin really. It scrolls to the point in the page where the anchor is. If that's hidden by the header, you would have to change the code in onePageNav to offset the scroll amount by the header height. something like `offset += headerHeight` perhaps. But that's outside the context of this question, so I'd try it and then if you have problems raise another question.

Comment: ok thank you Richard Hunter, i added a picture (.gif) in my post if you want to see the event :)

Comment: @RichardUnder i found it :  `scrollTop: offset -= 203`